# grammatical elements in 'as + ing'?

Tags: participles

In dictionary, I see phrases in the form of 'as + ing' quite many times, for example,

> attribute : regard something **as being caused** by (something or
>   someone)

Is 'as' here a preposition or conjunction? And how the past participle 'being caused' is used here? (As adjective or adverb?) If I rephrase the above sentence, is it just *"regard something as it is caused by (something or someone)"*?

I think actually the way I understand the above sentence is more like *"regard something as a (or the) thing (being) caused by (something or someone)"*.

All I want is to rigorously understand the meaning of the above sentence in the dictionary, and the usage of '*as*' and participles as in here. So far I cannot find a single reference that gives a proper explanation on the usage of '*as*' as in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *as* really belongs with *regard*: *regard as* is a [phrasal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb). In this case *as* is a preposition, but it doesn't have a meaning of it's own, only the unit *regard as* has a meaning.

This is tricky because phrasal verbs in English can be split up like this with the object.

The *being caused* is the 'indirect object' or second argument. In this case it's [a passive gerund participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_non-finite_verbs_in_English#Uses_of_nonfinite_verbs). But it could easily be many other things. Here are some examples of the verb *regard as*:

> John is regarded as a world expert.
>   I regard John as being a world expert.
>   I regard you as my friend.
>   John is regarded as the cause of the event.

Comment: any reference may you give me for the gerund thing?

Comment: @julypraise What do you mean sorry?

Comment: I'm looking for any textbook or anything where I can study passive gerund participle. Any suggestion?

Comment: No sorry. I'm not sure it actually is one. It could be a past participle instead. *being* is a passive gerund though...